# Beginner C loop function

Tags: c, function

I just started venturing into C coming from PHP. I'm having trouble with the `printf()` function when its called from within another function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printloop (int valx) {
    int x;
    for (x = valx; x < 5; x++) {
        printf("Value of x is: %d\n", x);
    }
}

int main() {
    printloop(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The program will compile and run but there is no output on screen.

Comment: It is quite natural because `5 < 5` is false. What is your problem?

Comment: There must be output be output on the screen.

Comment: Damn!!!! Silly me... Am completely out of my mind!!!

Comment: change `<` by `<=`

Comment: printloop(0); try that,   printloop(5); would exit without printing

Comment: printloop(5) would make more sense logically. It's not the function call that is wrong it is the logic of the function. He's starting the index at the ending condition, instead of at the starting condition.

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo/too localized, as I doubt this question will be of future interest to anyone, including the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong here is that your logic is saying 5 < 5, which is false.  Your `for` loop is not executing because when your printloop function is invoked at  `printloop(5);` it is passing the integer value of 5.

```
void printloop (int valx) {
int x;
for (x = valx; x < 5; x++) {
    printf("Value of x is: %d\n", x);
}
```

Your printloop function is receiving a value of 5, setting x inside of your function to x = 5.

When it is time for your for loop to execute you will have

```
void printloop (int valx) {
    int x = 5;
    for (5 = valx; 5 < 5; 5++) {
        printf("Value of x is: %d\n", x);
    }
}
```

the `for` loop will see 5 < 5, which is false, and thus the loop will not execute.

I think what you want to say is

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printloop (int valx) {
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < valx; x++) {
        printf("Value of x is: %d\n", x);
    }
}

int main() {
    printloop(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Which will output:

```
Value of x is: 0
Value of x is: 1
Value of x is: 2
Value of x is: 3
Value of x is: 4
```

I hope this makes sense, and keep up the good work!

Comment: Yes it does. What I have asked is actually terrible!!!! Its such a basic mistake that I feel ashamed!! Am out of my mind..

Comment: This is the real output with `for (x = 0; x <= valx; x++) {`??  Maybe `<`?

Answer (score 6):

When you invoke the `printloop` function with `5` the for loop essentially becomes

```
for (x = 5; x < 5; x++) {
    //...
}
```

And `x < 5` will never be true.

---

I guess what you meant was something like

```
for (x = 0; x < valx; x++) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main, your are calling printloop and giving it the value 5. This means that you're making valx = 5 and when you say `x = valx` inside of your loop, you're setting x equal to 5 as well. When your loop gets to its conditional, it will never run because because x is equal to 5, not less than it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printloop (int valx) {
int x;
    for (x = valx; x < 5; x++) {<--- **Your problem is here ( x = 5; x < 5; x++)
    printf("Value of x is: %d\n", x);
    }
}

int main() {
    printloop(5);
 return 0;
}
```

You are telling the loop while it is less than 5 (which it is not because of the value you gave to valx) thus it doesn't print anything because it doesn't go into the loop

Answer (score 0):

It's because you passed 5 to the function printloop, and the for loop inside printloop will only run if the given argument is less than 5. You could either change that value or pass an integer smaller than 5.